# Link to the next page (next in alphabetical order in the directory) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create buttons on my local html web-page so that they can link to the next page in alphabetical order...
Meaning that I have a directory named "dictionary" for example in which separate pages are made say for different letters of english alphabet which contain different details, word-meanings etc for each alphabet.

Now let's say I have opened the page: `dictionary/c.html`, then I want the following buttons: **Next Page** (which should take me to `dictionary/d.html`), and **Previous Page** (which should take me to `dictionary/b.html`)...similarly for all the other pages.

The problem is that I am using a template page using which I create all other pages (a to z), and I don't want to explicitly link the buttons in html, I rather want to use common `<script>` code snippets (one for previous and one for next) which I can add to my template page, using which I can create all other pages.

**(NOTE: actually I have the the pages numbered as 1.html, 2.html, 3.html ... so it is easier to code)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current page number with the following snippet:

```
let path = document.location.pathname
let lastPath = path.split('/')[path.split('/').length - 1]
let currentPageNumber = +lastPath.split('.')[lastPath.split('.').length - 2]
```

Then you can redirect using:

```
window.location.href = "https://yoursite/" + (currentPageNumber + 1) + ".html";
```